# How to use escape character for $$ in stored procedure in Snowflake

Tags: java, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE validateQuery() returns String 
LANGUAGE java 
RUNTIME_VERSION = '11' 
packages=('com.snowflake:snowpark:1.2.0') HANDLER ='ValidateQuery.validateQuery' as 
$$ 
public class ValidateQuery{ public static String validateQuery(Session session) { return "String Contain $$";}} 
$$
```

Use "$$" in Snowflake stored procedure

Answer (score 2):

If you use $$ to terminate the opening and closing of the stored procedure body, you cannot have $$ in anywhere in the body. I don't know of any escape sequences, but you can use string concatenation instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE validateQuery()
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  RUNTIME_VERSION = '11'
  PACKAGES = ('com.snowflake:snowpark:latest')
  HANDLER = 'ValidateQuery.validateQuery'
  AS
  $$
    import com.snowflake.snowpark_java.*;

    public class ValidateQuery {
      public String validateQuery(Session session) {
        return "String Contains $" + "$";
      }
    }
  $$;
```

| VALIDATEQUERY |
| --- |
| String Contains $$ |